# How to disable the #hashbang redirect on IE8 and IE9 in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, hashbang

I have an angularjs (v 1.2.19) application that consists of two separate html pages (or actually these are two seperate angularjs apps in one folder):

- index.html
- edit.html

I am having some well-known compatibility issues on IE 8 and 9 (both do not support the html5 history API). 
My config contains: `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');`

I do not have any routing in the application - index.html and edit.html can be seen as separate angularjs apps - that have separate angularjs initialization, etc.

The problem looks like this:
Whenever I open the link: `http://server/app` or `http://server/app/index.html` everything works fine.

Whenever I open the link: `http://server/app/edit.html` from ng-click or directly in the browser the page is automatically redirected to `http://server/#!app/edit.html`

How can I disable the "hashbang" redirection? Edit.html is not a part of the index.html, so it should be loaded directly without any index.html redirection and "hash" routing.

I tried the code located below, but it leads to infinite loop of redirections...

```
<!--[if lt IE 10]>
    <script>   
        window.location = window.location.href.replace( /#.*/, "");
    </script>
<![endif]-->
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Maybe it needs to be tweaked on server side (rewriting in html5 mode). There is a FAQ entry about that in ui-router project, see https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I do not get, however, what should I rewrite to what. In the end the problem boils down to the fact, that I've got an angular app, that's not under index.html. Whenever I try to open that link in the IE8/IE9 browser the links get rewritten by angular and the # is added. What should be the link that I should rewrite to using Apache2, etc?

Comment: possible duplicate of [10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting! when using $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17146461/10-digest-iterations-reached-aborting-when-using-locationprovider-html5mod)

Comment: How about making a directive that makes sure the full window redirect will happen?

It could be an attribute you add to an <a> tag that watches for clicks and forces the window.location to this.href?

Answer (score -1):

Try to disable html5mode
`$locationProvider.html5Mode(false).hashPrefix('!');`
or remove this string completely.