# URL change in outlook 2010

Tags: angularjs, url, outlook, internet-explorer-9

I develop an application who send some private link by mail to internal customer but I've a problem.

we are using outlook 2010 and we have IE 9 as default on our machines.

When the customer click on the link "http://exemple.com/request.html?id=foo", 
the link on the browser move in "http://exemple.com/#/request.html?id=foo" and so don't goes to the correct page

If we use firefox as default browser, there's no problem...
I can access to the apache server if i need

Do you have any idea how to fix it ?

Comment: Do you have any Outlook or Internet Explorer add-ins installed on the remote machine?

Comment: It seems the URL is changed in Internet Explorer, not Outlook.

Comment: Yes it's when i follow the link from outlook that th link change ... I use Angular Js in the pages is it possible that may cause somme issues ?

Comment: in this post I have a workaround http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24797570/how-to-disable-the-hashbang-redirect-on-ie8-and-ie9-in-angularjs
but I need locator

Answer (score 0):

The problem came from the routing of angularJS.

i wasn't making routes but IE9 force it, so he didn't find anything and redirect to homepage

I solved doing hashbang routing in all my application.

regards